# R Count Words in String Only Once

Tags: r, set

My data looks something like this:

```
df <- c("I am a car","I will","I have","I give","A bat","A cat")
df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c("text")
df$count <- str_count(df$text, regex("a{1}?",ignore_case = T))
```

I want to count just the one instance of 'a' in the first row, not every time that it appears in the whole string. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps we need `grep`

```
as.integer(grepl("\\ba\\b", df$text, ignore.case=TRUE))
```

---

Or using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
as.integer(str_detect(df$text, "\\ba\\b"))
#[1] 1 0 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: @Arun The `\\b` indicates word boundary.  So essentially, either `" a "` or that will work

Comment: ah! my bad.. I was thrown away by the sample answer.. Also, didn't know of `\\b` thanks for the tip!

Comment: Although another question, if I wanted to loop through a list of words, what goes in for a? Is it something like "\\b",i,"\\b"?

Comment: @dhrice One option is `paste0("\\b(", paste(words, collapse="|"), ")\\b")`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you again!